# GreenDao - Android - OnUpgrade not being called (Encrypted Database)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, upgrade, database-migration, greendao

I'm using **GreenDao 3.2.2** for my DB,

On my first run on creating Entities via @tags everything worked ok.

Now I am editing the gradle schema to higher versions because I added some props to a table:

```
greendao {
    schemaVersion 4
}
```

However the OpenHelper `onUpgrade` method is never called, thus my project is always crashing because some columns are not found.

**Application class**

```
//Init DB
        UpgradeHelper helper = new UpgradeHelper(this, ENCRYPTED ? "db-encrypted" : "db", null);
        Database db = ENCRYPTED ? helper.getEncryptedWritableDb("app-cipher") : helper.getWritableDb();
        daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
```

**OpenHelper class**

```
public class UpgradeHelper extends DaoMaster.OpenHelper {

    public UpgradeHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       //never gets called
        Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);

        //do migrations
    }
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have access to the created DB? Can you open it with SQLiteStudio?

Comment: @MatPag yes i can

Comment: @MatPag the PRAGMA user_version command is giving the correct SCHEMA_VERSION defined in gradle and DaoMaster :(  , however my table is not updated to the latest scheme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!!! After hours of searching and reading GreenDAO code I understood the problem.

The problem is that `getEncryptedWritableDb`  creates another kind of DB that does not extends `SQLiteDatabase`. So even when the `EncryptedHelper` gets the `onUpgrade` method, my helper class didn't catch it because it fell into another signature.

The solution was simply using the other signature that receives a DAO `Database` interface:

```
 public void onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by migrating all tables data");

        //do migration

    }
```

of course I needed to update all my Migration methods to receive a `Database` object instead of a `StandardDatabase`

Comment: Good to know ;)